# JSon with HighCharts and ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, highcharts

I'm new using highcharts and JSON.

My javascript code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'grafica',
            type: 'spline'
        },
        series: [{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('ajax/gettipomov.aspx', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

And the data returned by the server and received by JavaScript is this:

```
[{"tipoMov":"Ajuste negativo","valorTipoMov":5},{"tipoMov":"Ajuste     positivo","valorTipoMov":5},{"tipoMov":"Compra","valorTipoMov":5},    {"tipoMov":"Transferencia","valorTipoMov":5},{"tipoMov":"Venta","valorTipoMov":5}]
```

The problem is that chart is not showing any data, the chart is blank: [image](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2593/id7y.png)
The JSON Encoding that I use is:

```
var encoder = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return encoder.Serialize(obj);
```

Comment: This format is not supported, instead of `tipoMov` and `valorTipoMov` should be `name` and `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the format expected:

```
{ "name": "Ajuste negativo", "y": 5 },
{ "name": "Ajuste positivo", "y": 5 },
{ "name": "Compra", "y": 5},
{ "name": "Transferencia", "y": 5},
{ "name": "Venta", "y": 5}
```

`tipoMov` and `valorTipoMov` mean nothing to `Highcharts`, so change your `Object` to return the properties named accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but i can´t format this from C# code, i will try make this with the returned code in javascript.

Thanks!